# How can I add a detailed material/texture to a curve?

Tags: texturing, materials, bezier-curves

I know how to add a material/color to a curve, but I want to add it like a detailed texture, like the sphere on the right of the image, as you can see if I render the image (left image) the curve is still just red, it doesn't have the level of detail of the real material/texture.

Is there any good way to do it? *I was thinking on converting the curve into a mesh and then just add more polygons...it could work, but if in the future I need to change the curve shape, that won't help at all.*

[image]

Comment: Is this just a normal map? If so, it should be using the generated coordinates. Double check your node setup, you may need to add a *Texture Coordinate* input node.

Comment: Where do i have to put the Texture Coordinate input node? and also, if i want to add a texture, and one that i want to show on the curve, which kind of configuration it will need to have?

Comment: And yes, it's a bump-normal map for now, but after that i was thinking in add an image too..

Comment: It is supposed to utilize the generated UV coordinates by default . . .

Comment: Ah! Looking closer, the bumps *are* there, but very stretched out. You need to add a *mapping* node going into the Vector of your image texture. You will then be able to easily adjust the scale. Notice that you might need to add a texture coordinate input as well, going into the back of the mapping node.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bumps are showing up on the curve, however they are very stretched out. You need to add a *Mapping* node to adjust the scale of the texture with. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and select *Vector > Mapping*:

[image]

Now press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> again and select *Input > Texture Coordinate*:

[image]

Now take these nodes and set them up as shown:

[image]

By changing the *Scale* values you can now change the size of the texture you are using.

Notice that it will repeat/tile, so it is best to have a seamless/tileable texture.